# While loop with examples 47, 4477 , 23 or 2233

Tags: while-loop

can someone explain me while loop of this program using examples ...please 
Eg 4477,47

```
while (x > 0) {
         if (x % 10 == 4) 
            ++ cnt4; 
         else if (x % 10 == 7)
                ++ cnt7; 
              else flag = false;
                 x /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it and watching the variables to see what it does?

Comment: I did , but I can't understand how it is running ?

Comment: Suppose if input is x=4477, how is it going to work...?

Answer (score 0):

You may have troubles reading the `%` operator. This operator computes the rest of the Euclidian division.
For instance `10 % 5` = 0 and `10 % 3` = 1 because 10 / 3 = 3 and 1 is the rest

If `x` is not an integer, the behaviour can be different according to your language (`C` or `PHP` I guess)

```
while (x > 0)
{
    // will increase cnt4 by 1 if the rest of the euclidian division of x by 10 is 4
    if (x % 10 == 4) ++ cnt4;

     // will increase cnt7 by 1 if the rest of the euclidian division of x by 10 is 7
    else if (x % 10 == 7) ++ cnt7;

    // all conditions above failed
    else flag = false;

    x /= 10; // x = x / 10
}
```

Comment: By taking an example x=47 or x=4477 can you explain this to me by including  comments step wise? Please

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do it yourself using the tips I provided